# Service Fabric reliable service with .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric

So I am playing around with Service Fabric for rolling out a system to the cloud, and so far I have most of the stateless services ported over and running well using ASP.NET Core.

I have another set of services that need to be stateful, and I would like to leverage .NET Core for those services as well. For those I will need to run a custom TCP protocol, not HTTP/WebAPI/WCF.

So the question is; is this possible? The templates only have a ASP.NET Core stateless service template. Can I build something like a .NET Core console application to run as a "Reliable Service"? If so, is there any documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can create the .NET 4.5.1 stateful service via the template, and then port that project to .NET Core - we've done this and it works just fine.

There doesn't appear to be any official documentation on this process.

Comment: Thanks, the port was easier than I expected.